# Why is the empty result turning?

Tags: c#, string, properties, prop

Firstly, my English is bad, I'm sorry.

I want  `textbox` (in Form2.cs) text to displaying MainForm.cs
When I apply the following codes, displaying blank message.

**MainForm.cs**

```
private void btnFilitre_ItemClick(object sender,DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     ...
     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.Show();
}

private void workingFunction()
{
    CommClass com = new CommClass();
    MessageBox.Show(comm.Sorgu ); 
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form1 f1 = new Form1();
     CommClass comm = new CommClass();
     comm.Sorgu = textBox1.Text;
     f1.workingFunction();
     Hide();
 }
```

**CommClass.cs**

```
 public string Sorgu { get; set; }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are instantiating a new instance of CommClass in each place. workingFunction is not using the same CommClass you declared in the button1_click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the argument in.  In Form1 make this change:

```
public void workingFunction(CommClass comm)
{
    MessageBox.Show(comm.Sorgu ); 
}
```

And in Form2, you will need to keep track of your Form1 reference, instead of creating a new one, and then pass in your `CommClass` object:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommClass comm = new CommClass();
    comm.Sorgu = textBox1.Text;
    f1.workingFunction(comm);
    Hide();
}
```